# Is there a formal system in Linguistics like Boolean algebra to reduce the grammar rules of a language to minimum items ignoring semantics?

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar, grammar-formalism

To get the grammar rules down to the minimum **necessary** for teaching. Semantics not included.

[This is example what what I am thinking about](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MHS6xJDF7WxL2Gh6MZH1RoUmImh-VBzUMXIIXbKhV_k/edit?usp=sharing).

Grammar with all the semantics cut out, means it is easy to optimise the **learning process**.

Comment: Languages have their own logic and don't have minimum items.

Comment: Teaching a language while ignoring semantics seems like an incredibly bad idea. Without semantics there is no language to teach!

Comment: @curiousdannii That sounds like saying you cannot learn about chains without learning about slaves.

Answer (score 2):

There are various such systems. You could start with the systems of *The sound pattern of English* and *Aspects of the theory of syntax*, because they were widely used and have learnable formalisms. A problem with later theories is that they tend to require the student to know a lot of theory because there aren't actually any rules in a grammar. There is actually a textbook, Marina Burt's red book, for teaching basic syntax.

One problem is that you would need teachers who know those systems, and 99.999% of grammar school teachers have no knowledge of linguistics. Another problem is that grammar isn't necessarily on the curriculum in schools these days, and what passes for "grammar" in schools has little if anything to do with the grammatical structure of languages.

Comment: Like, how do you express all of the non-semantics related grammar with the minimum about of instructed ‍ information? Like finding the minimum cut sets with Boolean algebra.

Comment: , that's  above ‍.  references above.